# Conditional expectation implied by expectation of product

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, finance

For uni I have got the following assignment, and I've gotten stuck at (b). I have proven that E[1_{bi}X] = E[1_{bi}X], but don't know how I would get from this to the required conclusion. Does anyone have hints on how to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: $1_{B_i}1_{B_j}=0$ for $i \neq j$.  Also, any set in $\mathcal G$ is a union of some of  the $B_i$'s.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy im sorry i do not see how that could lead to the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **definition** of $Y=E[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ is that $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and satisfies
$$E[1_A X] = E[1_A Y], \; \forall A \in \mathcal{G}.$$

You've already showed that this holds when $A$ is one of the $B_i$, but you need to show it holds for other sets in $\mathcal{G}$. Kavi Rama Murthy is pointing out that the other sets of $\mathcal{G}$ are unions of the $B_i$. (Can you justify why?) Then, for example, can you check that the above equality holds when $A$ is $B_1 \cup B_2$?